Use variable from ViewModel in Activity. Best practices
I have three List on the VM that I want to use in the activity.
These Lists won't change on time, will always be the same, so it is not a State.
Should I do the following on the activity?
private val gymListViewModel: GymListViewModel by viewModels()
val myList1 = gymListViewModel.list1
val myList2 = gymListViewModel.list2
val myList3 = gymListViewModel.list3

Is that correct?
Or what I should do is use LiveData or Flow to be listening on the activity?
Or maybe I should create a data class with three val so I just call that object on the activity?
The other thing that I've been thinking is to call the method that populates the lists, something like:
val myList1 = gymListViewModel.getList1()
But if I'm not wrong, it's supposed that the VM should not have returning methods, they just update the state.
I'm asking this in terms of best practices.
Thanks

In terms of best practice, yes, using Flow/Livedata is recommended to expose data to your activity, mainly because of lifecycle awareness/state, even if the data is not changing.
But in terms of fast execution, I would just create the variable on my Viewmodel and call directly on the Activity.

There is an another option that using ImmutableList and expose variables directly if the List never be changed.

You can directly access the lists from the ViewModel without involving LiveData or Flow if they are static and immutable.
class GymListViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val list1: List<String> = listOf("Item1", "Item2", "Item3")
    val list2: List<String> = listOf("Item4", "Item5", "Item6")
    val list3: List<String> = listOf("Item7", "Item8", "Item9")
}

class GymActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val gymListViewModel: GymListViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gym)

        val myList1 = gymListViewModel.list1
        val myList2 = gymListViewModel.list2
        val myList3 = gymListViewModel.list3

        // Use the lists as needed
    }
}

